# How to display List and Details on the same view in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to be able to display List and detail on the same view, i am using a viewmodel that combines the properties of the two views/models, i am using tab control, i want to be able to display detail view on the first tab and list and list on the second tab. i have tried this:

```
 var clientInfo = (from c in db.Customers
                          join a in db.Addresses
                              on c.ClientId equals a.CustomerId 
                          where c.RowId == 19
                          select new
                          {
                              // corporate starts here
                              c.ClientId,
                              c.ClientGroup,
                              c.ClientCategory,
                              c.ClientType,
                              c.ContactName,
                              c.OrgName,
                              c.Branch,                                

//Address Starts here
                              a.AddressLine1,
                              a.AddressLine2,
                              a.State,
                              a.City,
                              a.CreatedDate,
                              a.ModifiedDate

                          }).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(clientInfo);
```

View for client details:

```
<dt>
                                               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientType)
                                           </dt>

                                           <dd>
                                               @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ClientType)
                                           </dd>

                                           <dt>
                                               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientId)
                                           </dt>

                                           <dd>
                                               @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ClientId)
                                           </dd>

                                           <dt>
                                               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
                                           </dt>

                                           <dd>
                                               @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
                                           </dd>
```

View for Addresses:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="sample-table-1">

                                           <tr>
                                               <th class="hidden-xs">
                                                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientId)
                                               </th>
                                               <th class="hidden-xs">
                                                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddressLine1)
                                               </th>
                                               <th class="hidden-xs">
                                                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddressLine2)
                                               </th>
                                               <th class="hidden-xs">
                                                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
                                               </th>

                                               <th class="hidden-xs">
                                                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
                                               </th>
                                               <th class="hidden-xs">
                                                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedDate)
                                               </th>
                                               <th class="hidden-xs">
                                                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModifiedDate)
                                               </th>
                                               <th class="hidden-xs">
                                                   User Action
                                               </th>
                                               <th class="hidden-xs"></th>
                                           </tr>

                                           @foreach(var item in Model)
                                           {
                                               <tr>
                                                   <td class="hidden-xs">
                                                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.)
                                                   </td>
                                                   <td class="hidden-xs">
                                                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Firstname)
                                                   </td>
                                                   <td class="hidden-xs">
                                                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Othernames)
                                                   </td>
                                                   <td class="hidden-xs">
                                                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                                                   </td>

                                                   <td class="hidden-xs">
                                                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StateName)
                                                   </td>
                                                   <td class="hidden-xs">
                                                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LgaName)
                                                   </td>
                                                   <td class="hidden-xs">
                                                       <a href="@Url.Action("edit", "users", new { id = item. })" class="btn btn-xs btn-teal tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit">class="fa fa-edit"></a>
                                                       <a href="@Url.Action("details", "users", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-xs btn-green tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="View List">class="fa fa-eye"></a>
                                                        <a href="@Url.Action("delete", "users", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-xs btn-bricky tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete">class="fa fa-trash-o"></a>
                                                   </td>
                                               </tr>
                                           }


                                       </table>
```

I want to be able to display this on the same view, i dont know how this can be possible, i will appreciate any assistance. thanks

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish it.  Ultimately "list" and "details" are just words.  What you're doing in either case is writing HTML and binding it to a ViewModel.  If your ViewModel contains all of the details for every item on the list, then you can create a list where every item has all of the details.  Style those items however you like.  For example, maybe have a basic item header with a few details and a hidden `div` with all the details, and users can "expand" and "collapse" individual elements.

Comment: I know how to display multiple model  in one view using ViewModel, where i am having issue is displaying List requires model IEnumerable<ViewModelName> to run while displaying Details  require @model ViewModelName to run

Comment: If you have a list of view models, then what's the problem?  Just loop over the list.

Comment: if i had wanted to display them on different views, i wouldnt have issues, my issue here is that a view can only accept only one @model directive, to display list of records i will need model IEnumerable<ViewModelName>, while Details will require model ViewModelName

Comment: I really don't know how to explain this any simpler.  When you have a collection of view models, you also have each individual view model.  Do you understand what an IEnumerable is?  It's a *collection*.  It *contains* the individual elements you're looking for.  You *have all of the data you need*.  What you're saying is, "I need an apple.  But all I have is a basket full of apples.  How do I get just an apple?"  Think about it for a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a viewmodel that contains both a IEnumerable and another model.
This would allow you to list items in a table and show a details view for the other model.

```
public class IndexViewModel{
   public IEnumerable<AddressListItem> List { get;set; }
   public ClientInfo Details {get;set;}
}
```

If you want to show details of one item from the list you have to create an action or Javascript to load the selected item into the details view.

You can create two new classes to hold the different properties.
And then assign them to the a IndexViewModel in the action.
It could look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var model = new IndexViewModel();
     var clientInfo = (from c in db.Customers
                      join a in db.Addresses
                          on c.ClientId equals a.CustomerId 
                      where c.RowId == 19
                      select new ClientInfo
                      {
                          ClientId = c.ClientId,
                          ClientGroup = c.ClientGroup,
                          ClientCategory = c.ClientCategory,
                          ClientType = c.ClientType,
                          ContactName = c.ContactName,
                          OrgName = c.OrgName,
                          Branch = c.Branch,
                          AddressLine1 = a.AddressLine1,
                         AddressLine2 = a.AddressLine2,
                         State = a.State,
                         City = a.City,
                         CreatedDate = a.CreatedDate,
                         ModifiedDate = a.ModifiedDate
                       }).FirstOrDefault();
     model.Details = clientInfo;

     var addresses = (from a in db.Addresses 
                      where a.CustomerId == clientInfo.ClientId
                      select new AddressLineItem
                      {
                         AddressLine1 = a.AddressLine1,
                         AddressLine2 = a.AddressLine2,
                         State = a.State,
                         City = a.City,
                         CreatedDate = a.CreatedDate,
                         ModifiedDate = a.ModifiedDate
                       }).ToList();
     model.List = addresses;
     return View(model);
 }
 }

 public class ClientInfo{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientGroup { get;set; }
    public string ClientCategory {get; set; }
    public string ClientType {get; set; }
    public string ContactName {get; set; }
    public string OrgName {get; set; }
    public string Branch {get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 {get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 {get; set; }
    public string State {get; set; }
    public string City {get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate {get; set; }
}

public class AddressListItem{
    public string AddressLine1 {get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 {get; set; }
    public string State {get; set; }
    public string City {get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What if i have other properties for ClassX and ClassY, do i need to include those properties in the IndexViewModel? Also, how do i use this in the controller action?

Comment: I updated my answer with some extra code samples. Added two classes and showed how to use the classes in a controller action to fetch data.

Comment: Thank you very much, but you are not returning the object to the view, what am i going to use at the @model directive in the view

Comment: You're right it should pass the model in the view and then you can use @model IndexViewModel in your view to access it. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the details in a partial view and update it with ajax.